# different mainnet address types

Tags: litecoin

1-ltc can transfer from p2pkh L-address to p2sh deprecated 3-address?
2-ltc can transfer from p2pkh L-address to p2sh new M-address?
3-ltc can transfer from p2pkh L-address to native segwit bech32 address?
4-ltc can transfer from p2sh deprecated 3-address to p2pkh L-address?
5-ltc can transfer from p2sh deprecated 3-address to p2sh new M-address?
6-ltc can transfer from p2sh deprecated 3-address to native segwit bech32 address?
7-ltc can transfer from p2sh new M-address to p2pkh L-address?
8-ltc can transfer from p2sh new M-address to native segwit bech32 address?
9-ltc can transfer from p2sh new M-address to p2sh deprecated 3-address?
10-ltc can transfer from native segwit bech32 address to p2pkh L-address?
11-ltc can transfer from native segwit bech32 address to p2sh new M-address?
12-ltc can transfer from native segwit bech32 address to p2sh deprecated 3-address?
thanks for answers before

Comment: Hi Ashkian, questions about Litecoin are not on-topic on this site, we only collect topics that are applicable to Bitcoin. However, in this case, I would expect that the answer in general is the same as for the Bitcoin question I linked.